# making this code dynamic and taking user input string for algorithm implementation

Tags: c

This program does not take any user input for a string
I want to take user input strings
and that to having dynamic allocation

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <string.h>

 void search(char* pat, char* txt)
{
   int M = strlen(pat);
   int N = strlen(txt);


   for (int i = 0; i <= N - M; i++) {
       int j;


        for (j = 0; j < M; j++)
          if (txt[i + j] != pat[j])
              break;

        if (j == M) // if pat[0...M-1] = txt[i, i+1, ...i+M-1]
          printf("Pattern found at index %d \n", i);
    }
}

int main()
{
   char txt[] = "Rohan is a Weeb and Rohan plays sports";
   char pat[] = "Rohan";
   search(pat, txt);
   return 0;
 }
```

Make txt[] and pat[] a dynamic character array for a matching string algorithm program

Comment: learn to use `fgets()`.

Comment: Use large enough buffers for the input, e.g. `char txt[128];`

Comment: stackoverflow is not a free coding service!  We will help you debug code you have written.